# Program that can share my wifi connection over ethernet on Windows?

Tags: windows

My laptop is connected to my internet via wifi. I want to be able to share that connection to another device over ethernet. I know that this is supposed to be possible with the built in Windows feature (ICS) but it is horribly unreliable for me (and many others). I used Connectify PRO's free trial which offered this functionality and worked flawlessly. Unfortunately a full license is pretty costly.

Are there any free programs that would allow me to do this? I don't need anything fancy, just gotta share the connection. Thanks.

Comment: gonna keep this open so I can reflect on its existence in 15+ years.